# Blank screen comes on browser when client auth fails on jetty server

Tags: java, jetty

I have created a Java rest API using embedded jetty server and have enable client authentication. In client auth, I fetch the CN of client certificate and see if its the one which is allowed.
I have created a Filter class to handle above client authentication logic. However, when the client auth fails and filter is returns, there is no response which is sent back and a blank screen appears on browser from where the API was hit. Ideally it should respond with some error.
I am hitting the API from browser in which I have already added the valid client certificates

In the response object of filter, I have already added a return status in response and some other things to make it end the request but it didn't work.

```
Enabling client auth which configuring SslContextFactory:

SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
sslContextFactory.setKeyStore(keyStore);
sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("changeit");
sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("changeit");
sslContextFactory.setCertAlias("selfsignlatest");
sslContextFactory.setNeedClientAuth(true);
sslContextFactory.setTrustStore(keyStore);
sslContextFactory.setTrustStorePassword("changeit");
```

```
Filter class doFilter method:

@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.debug("Filtering incoming request....");
        boolean isValid = false;
        HttpServletRequest httpreq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpresp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        X509Certificate[] certificates = (X509Certificate[]) httpreq.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
        if(certificates!=null && certificates.length>0) {
            for(X509Certificate cert: certificates) {
                commanName = getCNfromDomainName(cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
                if(commanName!=null && commanName.equals("clientjetty")) {
                    isValid = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if(isValid) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }else {
            httpresp.reset();
            httpresp.setHeader("Connection", "close");
            httpresp.setStatus(HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            httpresp.flushBuffer();
            httpresp.sendError(-1);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace ...

```java
httpresp.reset();
httpresp.setHeader("Connection", "close");
httpresp.setStatus(HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
httpresp.flushBuffer();
httpresp.sendError(-1);
```

with ...

```java
httpresp.setHeader("Connection", "close");
httpresp.sendError(HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If an answer worked for you, it's customary to indicate that specific answer as "accepted". (there should be a gray checkmark next to the answer that you, the question asker, can check off indicating that it is the working answer)